# Integrating Paytm All in One SDK in react-native

Tags: react-native, paytm

**How to integrate paytm all in one SDK in react-native?**

I am okay with integrating with webview. But in paytm offical documentation, it is provided for java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paytm is in process of implementing support for All-In-One SDK in React-Native framework. This I had confirmed from the Paytm support. Hopefully by next week it shall be available.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement same in android activity ,
using nativeModule call that activity

Answer (score 0):

Please check the documentation on developer portal of paytm. Now the All-in-one SDK is supported for React native apps as well. basically a bridge has been given for react-native which can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Step 01: Install All one SDK .
Step 02: react-native run-android & cd android & ./gradlew clean.
Step 03: Pass all required parameters in ALLINONESDK. before call check if are using staging MID or Production MID.Pass the token
Step 04: Now you will get the response.
STEP 05: Before start working PAYTM, just cross check all the services are activated or not. Sometimes service stop by paytm for documentation purpose.
STEP 06: Now you can check the payment transactions status in Paytm Dashboard(Main Account only able to track TEST mode payments).